# WPF fail. Using a WPF page as an instance

Tags: wpf, navigation, instance, shared

Think about a WPF program that has 2 pages which you navigate between. (Upload and Crop)

In the first page, you load an image using a button, select the image, and your image appears in the WPF Image control. Then, you press the "Crop" button. That sends the navigation to the second page, which you can crop the image.

Then, you crop the image in the second page. Then you press "next". Next button must redirect you to the first page, but wait a minute, the image you loaded no longer exist in the page. Because it's a new page.

```
    Dim CropPage As New Crop(Crop_Bmp, Crop_BmpSource)
    Me.NavigationService.Navigate(CropPage)
```

You may think it's okay. Because we pass the parameters and we can refill the WPF Image controls using that parameters. But, there is actually 8 upload panels in the page 1. So, other ones are important.

Or think about another method I found. Instead of using a new page instance, navigate back that you used.

```
    Upload.Crop_Bmp = Crop_Bmp
    Upload.Crop_BmpSource = Crop_BmpSource
    Me.NavigationService.GoBack()
    Upload.Crop()
```

But in the second one, it throws errors.

"Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Then, back to the Upload page, I made the variables and functions "Shared". But then, more problems come up. Because you cannot edit the local variables unless you also make them Shared. So, all of the variables and functions need to be "Shared".

I'm searching about a solution for a few days and I could not get rid of them. What method should I use? Redirecting back, or opening a new instance?

In old-type applications, it was very easy. All was that:

```
    Form1.Crop_Bmp = Crop_Bmp
    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Crop()
```

And it was working perfectly. Because the forms were not instances like WPF pages. That's the reason I find WPF quite weird.

Comment: "you find WPF quite weird" because you're using a winforms mindset. forget everything you've ever learned in winforms and start learning the MVVM pattern. Otherwise you will fail in WPF. and don't blame WPF for that.

Comment: Oh, and start coding in C#. VB.Net is a toy language.

Answer (score 0):

I found it a way to do this. When navigating to the Crop page, I sent the Upload page as a parameter to Crop Page.

```
    Dim CropPage As New Crop(Crop_Bmp, Crop_BmpSource, Me)
    Me.NavigationService.Navigate(CropPage)
```

Then, in Crop:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Crop_Bitmap_ As Bitmap, ByVal Crop_BitmapSource_ As BitmapSource, ByVal pg As Upload)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    UploadPage = pg
```

Then, in the Crop page, I accessed that parameter to modify its elements. For example:

```
    Me.NavigationService.Navigate(UploadPage)
    UploadPage.Crop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad use-case for the Pages metaphor.   Pages are for loosely coupled peer screens (E.G.  A separate page for each department), but you are using them in a tightly coupled parent-child relationship.  (The "Crop" page is the child of the "Upload" page)  For what you are doing, launching the crop screen as modal dialog might be more fitting.

If you want to keep everything in the same window, you can keep both functions in the same window, and toggle their visibility as needed.